# How to solve complex least squares with real unknowns

Tags: fitting, complex

I am looking at the case where my least squares problem is of the form

$   y=A x $

where y is a vector of measured complex values, A is the model or design matrix, also complex, and x are the model coefficients which are real. How do I formulate the problem in Mathematica to get real values for my model coefficients?

Here is a minimum working example of what I have looked at.

First I make a noise free set of artificial data where my unknows are the values 1 to 7 and use the ordinary `LeastSquares` program to find my unknowns.

```
mat = RandomComplex[{-10 (1 + I), 10 (1 + I)}, {20,7}]; (* Design matrix *)
uk = Range[7]; (* Known unknowns *)
yy1 = mat . uk; (* Measured values *)
sol1 = LeastSquares[mat, yy1] (* Solution *)


(* {1. + 1.93795*10^-15 I, 2. - 2.22045*10^-16 I, 3. - 5.3385*10^-16 I, 
 4. - 2.02397*10^-15 I, 5. + 4.70461*10^-16 I, 6. - 5.55476*10^-16 I, 
 7. + 5.52099*10^-17 I} *)
```

As expected the real part of the solution is perfect and the imaginary part is numerical noise.

Now I put some noise into the measured values and use `LeastSquares` again.

```
yy2 = yy1 +  RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 20];(* Measured values with noise *)
sol2 = LeastSquares[mat, yy2] (* Solution *)

(* {1.02302 + 0.0244589 I, 2.00445 - 0.051833 I, 2.97412 + 0.0227336 I, 
 4.0041 - 0.00438793 I, 5.01066 - 0.0132584 I, 5.96674 + 0.0293913 I, 
 7.00924 + 0.00691532 I} *)
```

As expected there are now complex solutions although the imaginary parts are small.

I now attempt to do the matrix algebra the long way to get a solution with real values. There is probably a better way of doing the matrix algebra (please make suggestions). I finish by comparing the solutions from the three methods.

```
  xx = Array[x, 7]; (* Unknown unknowns *)
    ee = Sum[
ComplexExpand[(mat[[n]] . xx - yy2[[n]]) Conjugate[mat[[n]] . xx - yy2[[n]]]],
         {n, 20}]; (* Sum of errors *)
    mat3 = D[ee, #] & /@ xx; (* Take derivaties *)
    {vec, mat4} = CoefficientArrays[mat3, xx];(* Find LHS and design matrix *)
    sol3 = -Inverse[mat4] . vec ;(* Solve *)
    TableForm[Transpose[{sol1, sol2, sol3}], 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"Exact", "Complex Least Squares","Real Least Squares"}}]
```

[image]

So I have got my solution to have real values. However, I note that the errors in the real part of the `LeastSquares` solution are very similar to the errors in my real solution.

Two questions:

1. What is the best way to tackle this problem?
2. Is the `LeastSquares` solution just as good if I take the real part?

Note that my actual problem will have very large matrices.

Thanks

Comment: `PseudoInverse[mat].yy1`, `PseudoInverse[mat].yy2` and `-PseudoInverse[mat4] . vec` are alternative ways to solve

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Thanks but they give the same results as my methods...

Comment: It would be a bad alternative if not!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Do you have any idea about the internals of these codes?  How valid is taking the real part of the solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question. This turns out to be easier than I thought. Consider the problem where we have

$  y=A x   $

with y a column of complex measurements, A a matrix of complex values and x a vector of real unknowns. The objective is to find the real values of x via a least squares process.

Split the complex values into real and imaginary parts

$  y_r+i y_i=x \left(A_r+i A_i\right)  $

where the subscripts r, i mean real and imaginary parts.  This may be written as two equations which may be put into matrix form as

$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 y_r \\
 y_i \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 A_r \\
 A_i \\
\end{array}
\right) x $

With this configuration the `LeastSquares` function may be applied directly.

Here is an example.

```
nn = 100; (* Number of measurements*)
nk = 7; (* Number of unknowns *)
A = RandomComplex[{-10 (1 + I), 10 (1 + I)}, {nn, 
   nk}]; (* Design matrix *)
uk = Range[nk]; (* Known unknowns *)
y = A . uk + 
  RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 
   nn]; (* Measured values with complex noise *)
Ar = Re[A];
Ai = Im[A];
yr = Re[y];
yi = Im[y];
yy = Join[yr, yi];
AA = Join[Ar, Ai];
LeastSquares[AA, yy]

(* {0.997568, 1.99928, 3.00159, 3.99664, 5.00797, 5.98345, 7.00619} *)
```

So this works well.

Comment: This method assumes that the errors are independent (both between and within observations) and with a common variance.  Do the residuals back up those assumptions?

Comment: @JimB You make a good point about the statistical assumptions. The concern is with data  that are complex. If we assume that the complex data is derived via a Fourier transform then I would suggest the the real and imaginary parts are independent. Also, if the real time domain data has independent errors between observations then I think the complex data generated by Fourier transform would also be independent.  Such independence would allow for standard least squares methods.  However, do you have any insights into this area or can you suggest tests?

Comment: The answers here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/analysis-with-complex-data-anything-different might be helpful.